# I cannot use an exported function from another module in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, module, node-modules

I am getting an error

```
   createCustomers({ customerName, IsGold, PhoneNumber });
      ^

TypeError: createCustomers is not a function
```

The function that I am exporting is this:-

```
async function createCustomers(customerName, isGold, phone) {
  const customer = new Customers({
    customerName: customerName,
    isGold: isGold,
    phone: phone,
  });
  try {
    const result = await customer.save();
    console.log(result);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("Can't add Customers", err.message);
  }
}

module.exports.createCustomers = createCustomers;
```

and In another module, I import the function

```
const { createCustomers}  = require("../models/customers");

program
  .command("Add <customerName>  <IsGold> <PhoneNumber>")
  .alias("a")
  .description("Add a Customer")
  .action((customerName, IsGold, PhoneNumber) => {
      createCustomers( customerName, IsGold, PhoneNumber );
  });
```

I dont know why it not working event though I am exporting the function and loading it !

Answer (score 0):

you can export it like
module.exports = {createCustomers}

and import it as 
const createCustomers = require("../models/customers");